# How to set Uber driver app online or offline from my app in iOS

Tags: uber-api

I referred many links in google and Uber developer site. I didn't get exact result expected. We are using Uber rides SDK in my app. When tap on Uber icon, I need to open Uber driver app and make him online or offline and also set pick up time near some distance. Can any one explain me how to implement that?

Is it possible to implement in my app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently, there is no Uber API available that will give you this functionality - so unfortunately you cant change the status of the Uber Driver App by using the API.

Comment: Thank you Sasa. But this kind of functionality working in Mystro app for android. Why not in iOS.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=partners.driver.mystro&hl=en